# Unity/C# How to run Script continuously on User Interface Select Event Trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Complete beginner here, I'm looking to smoothly rotate my sphere continuously while the button it is a child of is selected in the UI.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class ButtonHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 rotationDirection = new Vector3(0, .25f, 0);
    private float smoothTime = 1;
    private float convertedTime = 200;
    private float smooth;
    public void SetText()
    {
        Transform target = transform.Find("Globe");
        smooth = Time.deltaTime * smoothTime * convertedTime;
        target.Rotate(rotationDirection * smooth);
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I go to select my button, the function is only ran a single time, whereas I want it to run continuously until deselected.

** Note this is using the Select Event Trigger

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please let me know if you need additional information to answer

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you could use the [Update()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) function (native to MonoBehaviour) to run the few lines of code that you have and rotate your sphere.

Then set up functions for when the button is clicked and when it is released to change a boolean variable that is evaluated in the Update() function...

Breif example below...

```
private bool rotate = false;

void Update()
{
    if (rotate)
    {
        Transform target = transform.Find("Globe");
        smooth = Time.deltaTime * smoothTime * convertedTime;
        target.Rotate(rotationDirection * smooth);
    }
}

public void StartRotation() //on click
{
    rotate = true;
}


public void StopRotation() //on release
{
    rotate = false;
}
```

Further improvements might include Finding the "Globe" object in the constructor and storing a reference to it for future use during rotation.

Another method involves setting the rotation speed of the sphere rather than directly transforming (rotating) it constantly (make the Physics Enginge do the work) but try this first to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Extending [Nicholas Sims' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58870104/7111561) a slightly better option would be a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Coroutines can be seen as temporary `Update` method as by default each iteration step is Don right after the `Update` call.

This way you don't waste resources to an `Update` method when the trigger is not activated anyway.

Also note that `Find` in general is a very expensive call and should be avoided wherever possible! The least you want to do is using it in `Update` every frame! Instead store the reference as early as possible .. maybe even already via a field in the Inspector!

```
// For storing the reference
// If possible already reference this via the Inspector 
// by drag&drop to avoid Find entirely!
[SerializeField] private Transform target;

private bool rotate;

private void Start()
{
    if(!target) target = GameObject.Find("Globe");
}

public void ToggleRoutine()
{
    rotate = !rotate;

    if(!rotate)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine (RotateContinuously());
    }
}

private IEnumerator RotateContinuously()
{
    // Whut? o.O
    // No worries, this is fine in a Coroutine as long as you yield somewhere inside
    while (true)
    {
        // You should use Find only once .. if at all. You should avoid it wherever possible!
        if(!target) target = transform.Find("Globe");
        smooth = Time.deltaTime * smoothTime * convertedTime;
        target.Rotate(rotationDirection * smooth);

        // Very important for not freezing the editor completely!
        // This tells unity to "pause" the routine here
        // render the current frame and continue
        // from this point on the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

---

If you rather want a "While Pressed" behaviour, so you want the rotation going on while the user holds the mouse/button pressed and stop as soon as he released it, you can use the `IPointerXYHandler` interfaces like

```
public class WhilePressedRotation : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;

    private void Start ()
    {
        if(!target) target = GameObject.Find("Globe");
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StartCoroutine(RotateContinuously());
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // Actually not really needed
        // but not sure if maybe required for having OnPointerExit work
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    private IEnumerator RotateContinuously()
    {
        // Whut? o.O
        // No worries, this is fine in a Coroutine as long as you yield somewhere inside
        while (true)
        {
            // You should use Find only once .. if at all. You should avoid it wherever possible!
            if(!target) target = transform.Find("Globe");
            smooth = Time.deltaTime * smoothTime * convertedTime;
            target.Rotate(rotationDirection * smooth);

            // Very important for not freezing the editor completely!
            // This tells unity to "pause" the routine here
            // render the current frame and continue
            // from this point on the next frame
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or a more general code

```
public class WhilePressedButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent whilePressed;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StartCoroutine(ContinuousButton());
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // Actually not really needed
        // but not sure if maybe required for having OnPointerExit work
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    private IEnumerator ContinuousButton()
    {
        // Whut? o.O
        // No worries, this is fine in a Coroutine as long as you yield somewhere inside
        while (true)
        {

            whilePressed.Invoke();

            // Very important for not freezing the editor completely!
            // This tells unity to "pause" the routine here
            // render the current frame and continue
            // from this point on the next frame
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And reference a method in `whilePressed` like usually in a button `onClick` via Inspector or code.