# Hold down UI button to perform an action in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple game in unity, and I decided to make it able to be played on mobile, so to move a cube I use the AddForce method inside of the update method, but now I added two buttons to move the cube, but the problem is that I have to make the action on a hold function instead of click one, so how is that done in unity?
something like this but with a button hold...

```
if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("[4]") || Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sideWaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

And I'm using Unity 2020.

Comment: Does [this (bottom part)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58870939/7111561) answer your question?

Comment: Just going to help clarify, use the code derHugo posted with IHandlers and move any physics processing code to FixedUpdate instead of Update. Store the most recent held buttons as variables and check them in FixedUpdate. If you need a specific code example sure derHugo can tweak their solution from the other post or I can add an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is you can add a rigidbody to the cube and make a script for the ui canvas. Once you done that, you can reference the cube like this : `public GameObject cube;`. Then in the update function what you can do is add some if statements checking if either button is pressed. And if for example the button that makes the cube move left is pressed, add a force to the cube on the x axis. I can give you a hint on how to do this : `cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(15, 0, 0)`. I'm sure you can figure the rest out by yourself.

I hope you found this useful! :D

Comment: Although moving AddForce to FixedUpdate is correct, OP wanted to know how to create a code snippet that emulated their example snippet but instead of using key inputs, used a UI hold instead.

Comment: what does "OP" mean? Also my bad for answering the question wrongly, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: OP is original post or original poster. It's referring to the asker or their question. Your answer wasn't necessarily wrong just not fully answered. The specific question is asking how to replicate the AddForce call when a UI element is held. Using IHandler events as recommended by derHugo in the comments is probably the best bet.

Comment: ok thanks! I should look more into IHandler since I never heard of that before.